# r shiny: allow user to download shiny output in a desired directory

Tags: r, download, shiny

In my Shiny app, I run calculations, generate a data frame, and want the user to be able to save (download) it.

My relevant code in ui.R:

```
textInput("downFile","Save the File:", value = "Results File"),
downloadButton('downFile',"Save File"),
```

My relevant code in server.R:

```
output$downFile <- downloadHandler(
  filename = function() {
    paste0(input$downFile, " ", Sys.Date(), ".csv") 
  },
  content = function(file) {
      write.csv(MyMainFunction()$mydataframe, file, row.names = FALSE)
  }
)
```

Everything works. But I have two issues:

1. If by mistake the user clicks on "Save File" before all the calculations in server.R have been completed, he gets an error ("Failed - Network Error").
2. After all the calculations, when the user clicks on the "Save File" button, the file is immediately saved in "Downloads" folder.

Two questions:

1. Is it possible to make the button invisible until the calculations in my main function (MainFunction) are completed?
2. How could I allow the user to select a desired folder to download the results to? (as in "Save in...")

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for question 1: Use shinyjs package learn more in https://deanattali.com/shinyjs/

```
  library(shinyjs)
   disable("downFile") # or use hide() Before all calculations 
   enable("downFile") # or use show() After
```

For question 2: I think this is more about setting up your browser than the shiny

If you are using chrome go to the advanced settings and enable

[image]

Comment: Thank you! You are right - for some reason that Chrome setting of mine was disabled. Unfortunately, I have absolutely no control over the settings of the user. :( I guess, they'll have to deal with it then.

Comment: Where should I place the disable and enable lines? Thank you!

Comment: Yép, complicated. Anyway if you need anything I'm at your disposal

Comment: I do not have access to your entire application, so it's difficult to respond. But
I imagine you wanted to start your application the disabled button, so you can leave disable () at the beginning of the server.

The enable () you place at the end of your function that executes the calculations