# how to download quarto pdf reports from R Shiny application

Tags: r, pdf, shiny, quarto

I am trying to download pdf/docx/html reports based on the inputs provided by user. To do that I created a Shiny app and a qmd file with parameters. qmd file is working fine when i render it separately. But if i render the same document and try to download it from Shiny it is not working. Here is my **downloadHandler** chunk

```
output$report <- downloadHandler(
filename = function() {
  paste("report", input$report_file_type, sep = ".")
},

content = function(file) {
  output <- quarto::quarto_render(
    input = 'report_template.qmd',
    output_format = input$report_file_type,
    execute_params = list(name = input$author_name,
                          report_title = input$report_title)
  )
  file.copy(output, file)
}
```

)

Edit: here is the qmd report template

````
---
title: "`r params$report_title`"
author: "`r params$name`"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`"
format: html
embed-resources: true
params:
  report_title: "report title"
  name: "author name"
  p_list: list("A", "B")
---

Printing each element of the list...

```{r}
#| echo: true
for(p in eval(parse(text = params$p_list))){
  print(p)
}
```

Printing the list...
```{r}
#| echo: true
print(eval(parse(text = params$p_list)))
```
````

I am not getting any error but at the same nothing is being written to downloads folder. It seems like rendered document is not being assigned to **output**. Perhaps that's why the coping line is not working. what could be the problem and how to solve it? thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide the `report_template.qmd`?

Answer (score 3):

`quarto::quarto_render` does not return the generated file or anything and so `output` in your code is `NULL` and hence you are not getting any output.

Now to get this code working, we need to copy the file generated by `quarto::quarto_render` to the `file` parameter of the function passed to `content` argument of `downloadHandler`.

```
shinyApp(
  
  # UI -----------------------------------------------------------
  ui = fluidPage(
    textInput("author_name", "Author Name", "John Doe"),
    textInput("report_title", "Report Title", "Quarto From Shiny"),
    radioButtons(
      inputId = "report_file_type",
      label = "Report Type",
      choices = c("HTML" = "html", "PDF" = "pdf")
    ),
    downloadButton("report", "Generate report")
  ),
  
  # SERVER --------------------------------------------------------
  server = function(input, output) {
    
    output$report <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {
        paste("report", input$report_file_type, sep = ".")
      },
      content = function(file) {
        quarto::quarto_render(
          input = "report_template.qmd",
          output_format = input$report_file_type,
          execute_params = list(
            name = input$author_name,
            report_title = input$report_title
          )
        )
        # copy the quarto generated file to `file` argument.
        generated_file_name <- paste("report_template", input$report_file_type, 
                                     sep = ".")
        file.copy(generated_file_name, file)
      }
    )
  }
)
```

Comment: i got the reason for reactive, but when I click the download button it is rendering the file and the directly opening it from the temp dir. I need an option to browse my dir and download it wherever i need to. is it possible to do that. thanks.

Comment: Can you try the updated code? `reactive` Exrepssion is not really needed here

Comment: I think Downloading to a specific directory is a different issue and it should be a different question. however, you may try the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48510501/r-shiny-allow-user-to-download-shiny-output-in-a-desired-directory)

Comment: Yes, reactive is not necessary since the template name is already there